# Read() in c: Reading extra chars

Tags: c

I am currently writing a program that will read a file according to a user given buffer, will write that to an output file, and will continue doing that until the file is done.  However, right now my output file has extra characters then it should have when compared to the original file. I think it has something to do with how read and write do not always return the number of bytes that is requested. I am unsure how to fix this.

Right now I just have a simple while loop:

```
while(read(inFD, buff, buf)!= 0)

   write(outFD, buff, buf);
```

buf is the user given buffer.

Thanks if you can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read` manual reads: "On success, the number of bytes read is returned".

You are ignoring the number returned; instead you are assuming `buf` bytes were read. In result, your output file size will be a multiple of `buf`.

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you!